# How to deactivate maven profile in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have a maven project in eclipse Indigo. The project's POM uses a certain profile by default, which I wish to disable from my eclipse. I know I can activate through right-click on project-->properties-->Maven-->Active Maven Profiles.

But how do I disable that profile?

Comment: I opened a [topic](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/757627/#msg_757627) about this in eclipse forums . Hope I'll get an answer. Maybe they'll tell me to file a new bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you should be able to add a ! prefix to the given profile, in the project > Properties > Maven > "Active Maven Profiles" field. But, there's a bug in m2e that prevent profiles to be explicitely deactivated : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337353

Sorry this doesn't constitute a solution to your issue, but you can at least now track progress on the resolution of the bug. And if you like living on the edge, you can clone m2e's git repo, apply the fix patch and build m2e from source.

Comment: Sure I like living on the edge. Though, since I'm trying to prepare work environment for the whole development section, I might encounter slight resistance ;)...

Comment: I guess that's the best one can get. And this answer would be a good reference when the bug will be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The fix for this bug has been committed, you can install a nightly build from https://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/forge-sites/m2e/1.1.0/N/LATEST/

Answer (score 0):

Add a new (empty) profile to your POM (e.g. 'eclipse') and set this as the active maven profile in your eclipse.

Comment: That's weird, it didn't work, although it states [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) that activating profile X deactivates the default profile Y... Maybe it's something with m2eclipse...

Comment: Very possible knowing m2eclipse; try to run the maven build from the command prompt using the eclipse profile (-P eclipse).

Comment: Well, at least this problem is maven's... It doesn't work from command line either. Only explicitly disabling the default profile (-P !defaultProfileName) actually disables it...

Comment: You can always remove the default active on that certain profile and and make it active (-P xxx) when run outside of eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, I know that... But that's running the risk people will forget to run mvn with one of the profiles and it'll fail in the wrong time and place... A good practice is to make the simple mvn install command not fail... I I'll have no choice I might do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another idea: have 2 maven settings.xml files: one default (in .m2 folder) where the above profile is activated and one for eclipse (wherever) where the profile is not activated.

Comment: BTW: interesting read: http://java.dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices

Comment: I figure it might be hard to manage different settings.xml files spread over our network...

Comment: I read that link... I can't just say I have two options: either the unwanted inherited behavior will always be performed (outside of any profile) or it'll in a default profile (which I assumed can be disabled from Eclipse...)